# I can not generate API for the Iphone someone can help me?

Tags: xcode, xamarin

I am trying to build an application in xamarin on windows connected to a mac mini but it is not working. the following message appears:

```
windows visual studio error message
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This version of Xamarin.iOS requires the iOS 12.2 SDK (shipped with Xcode 10.2). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only (to try to avoid the new APIs).  TRIP4VIP.iOS
```

I tried putting Visual Studio on MAC mini but it did not change anything, and I tried updating the xcode to version 10.12

I could not understand why the MAC mini can not upgrade to Mac OS 10.14?

The version of my MAC is 10.13.8 and I can not upgrade to 10.14 does anyone know how I can compile my project?

Note: I use third-party APIs

Comment: You're going to have to share some of your code with us

Comment: Do you think it's the code?

Comment: the error message is pretty clear: "This version of Xamarin.iOS requires the iOS 12.2 SDK (shipped with Xcode 10.2). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only".  If your mac cannot be upgraded to the latest version of MacOS, have you tried the other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions:**

1. Upgrade `Xcode` to 10.2 to get the required header files
2. If you are not able to upgrade the Mac system that Xcode 10.2 required. Change linker behaviour to `Link Framework SDKs Only`.

Steps to change linker behaviour: Before you run your project, right click `xxx.iOS project` --> `properties` --> `ios build` -->`linker behaviour`, change to `Link Framework SDKs Only`.

Add a screenshot here to make it clear:
[image: screenshot]